# How did I get +12 reputation for my up voted Answer?

Tags: discussion

I know reputation score goes up to +10 when others vote up our questions. But today I notice, I get +12 for [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/150542/25879).

How did I get *+12* reputation instead of *+10*. Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually two events:

- A up-vote
- A un-down-vote

The latter means a user took off their down-vote, and you gained back the 2 points you lost when you got down-voted.

> [image: screenshot]